# Flux Density for uniformly charged cylinder

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image: Coaxial Capacitor of Length L]

Given the inner cylindrical surface of radius "a" is charged with a constant uniform charge density of $\rho_s$, How did they derive this formula for Flux Density at distance r radially:

$\vec{D} = \rho_s \frac{a}{r}\hat{r}~~~[\frac{C}{m^2}]$

Where:

$\rho_s = \frac{\text{Charge}}{\text{Area}}~~~[\frac{C}{m^2}]$

$\vec{D} \propto \frac{1}{r}$

Comment: Do you know the Gauss theorem?

Comment: $\oint \limits_S \vec{D} \bullet d\vec{S} = Q_{\text{enclosed}}$

Comment: but, i think they did most of this by $\vec{D} = D \hat{r}$ then pulling D out of integral... so that D$\oint \limits_S \hat{r} \bullet d\vec{S} = D\oint \limits_S  dS$  and $\oint \limits_S  dS$ is just a surface area formula for a cylinder.

Comment: The integral is the flux, and thank to the symmetry can be be written as $ \Phi= 2\pi lrD$. Now write the enclosed charge in a similar way..

Comment: $D \oint \limits_S dS= Q_{enc}$  ....  (surface area of cylinder) $=2\pi a$... $\rho_s$ * (surface area of cylinder) = $Q_{enc}$?

Answer (score 1):

The symmetry ensure us that, at all points between the two surfaces, $\vec D$ is oriented as $\hat r$. and the Gauss Theorem , in your notation, say that, for the the flux, we have:

$\Phi=2\pi l r D= Q= \rho_s 2\pi a l $

From this we have:
$
D=\frac{a}{r}\rho_s
$
and the vector $\vec D$ has the direction $\hat r$ :

$\vec D=\frac{a}{r}\rho_s \hat r$